# Converting PSCustomObject to Hashtable

Tags: powershell, hashtable, pscustomobject

I'm having some problems converting some data from a json payload. The closest I've gotten is converting it to a PSCustomObject like below;

```
Fields
------
{@{short=true; title=Status; value=Status text.}, @{short=true; title=Type; value=Type text.}, @{short=false; title=Detail; value=This is some example detail text.}}
```

However I need to convert it to a Hashtable in the following format. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
short                          true
title                          Status
value                          Status text.
short                          true
title                          Type
value                          Type text.
short                          false
title                          Detail
value                          This is some example detail text.
```

Thanks,

Comment: It might be easier to start of from your json payload and show how that is structured. E.g. it is probably better to start with [`ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume your JSON has been converted to object `$obj`, you can do the following to output an array of hash tables.

```
$obj.Fields | Foreach-Object {
    $hash = [ordered]@{}
    $_.PsObject.Properties | Foreach-Object { 
        $hash[$_.Name] = $_.Value
    }
    $hash
}
```

Your output will need to be an array of hash tables because a single hash table cannot have duplicate key names.